# What tag to use when you don't know the technology involved?

Tags: discussion, tags

Suppose that you find a website that can do something impressive. I don't know, it can read your mind and output your thoughts in the screen or something.

Naturally, you want to know how did they do that. So you ask at Stack Overflow.

What tags is one supposed to use for such question?

---

The reason I ask is because, since you have absolutely no idea how is that website implemented, you can't exactly choose a tag. You can't tag it with [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) or [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) or [html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5) or [drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal), because you simply don't have the faintest idea what technology was used to effectively read your mind.

What is the correct tag for this, then? Or, actually: is this sort of question even permitted?

Comment: Please don't ask at all. How are we supposed to know how it was implemented? "Tell me how Facebook/Twitter/etc. works" is not a useful question, and you can substitute "etc." with any website with mind-reading or any other features on the Internet.

Comment: Hey, what's the problem with this question? I'm not *going* to make a question about how is something implemented. I'm just asking if you can, and the answer is no.

Comment: Don't worry, voting works differently on Meta. People use it to agree or disagree with a post (question or answer). That is why you are receiving downvotes.

Comment: This place is weird.

Comment: @JustKidding it is. But do not worry, those downvotes don't affect your real SO reputation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think such questions are off-topic because

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Or possibly even too-broad. Like, how could anyone possibly know how Google's "I am feeling lucky" or any other website was implemented from scratch to end? It just does not about a specific programming problem you're facing...There is no too-localized reason any longer but it would also apply as I honestly do not think such a question would benefit any future readers.

If you want to know the technologies implemented on a website why don't you ask the web admin directly?